# Backbone, get a Collection by collection ID (not RESTful)

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone collection where the collection is fetched by a url with an id parameter (not RESTful)

```
url: '/api/categories/?level=2&id=',
```

So id might be

```
&id=2
```

or

```
&id=45
```

How do I go about doing this? I've been reading different posts and some say to override Backbone Sync and others say to just do a fetch but modify the data parameters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you construct the `Collection`, pass the `id` as parameter (by default, `Collection` do not have an id property while `Model` do).

Then, override the `url` property of the `Collection` and pass a function:

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize : function(models, options) {
        this.id = options.id;
    },

    model : // Your Model class

    url: function() {
        return '/api/categories/?id=' + this.id;
    }

});

// [] is the initial, empty set of models
var coll = new MyCollection([], { id: 45 });

coll.fetch(); // the correct url will be called
```